# r: simulate a data matrix with a preset distribution

Tags: r, matrix, simulation

I want to simulate `one column` of `y` and `n*N` `x matrix` with `one column` as `y` and `N` columns as `x`.

```
 y x1 x2 x3 ... xN
 1  1  0  1 ... 1
 0  1  1  0 ... 1
 .  .  .  . ... .
 .  .  .  . ... .
 0  1  0  1 ... 1
```

At the same time, I need to simulate a data matrix `beta`, which is the coefficients between `y` and `x`. so the matrix will look like

```
 y  x1        x2      x3   ...   xN
 1  beta11  beta12  beta13 ... beta1N
 0  beta21  beta22  beta23 ... beta2N
 .    .        .      .    ...    .
 .    .        .      .    ...    .
 0  betan1  betan2  betan3 ... betanN
```

There is some relationship between `x` and `y`, but that is not the point of my question. The simulation scheme is:

n=100

N= 1000

p=0.5

1. y<- rbinom(n, 1, p) #I first generate the column with 100 rows for y
2. beta<- rnorm(n,0,1) #beta is the coefficient in the model with y and x
3. p1<-runif(n,0,1)
4. p2<-exp(beta)*p1
5. x<-rbinom(n,1,p2)#x is have relationship with  beta and p1, so x is sampled in this way.

The simulation scheme is just for generating `one column` with `n` observations of `y` and `one column` with `n` observations of `x`, so I need a `for` loop to create the `matrix` for `beta` and `x`.
My codes are：

```
n =100
N = 1000
p<- 0.52
y<- rbinom(n,1,p) #generate y

for (i in 1:N){

  beta[i] <-rnorm(n, 0, 1 )

  p1[i] <- runif(n, 0, 1)
  p2[i] <- exp(beta)*p1
  x[i]<- rbinom(n, 1, p2)
  }
```

The error occurs:

```
Error in beta[i] <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I think my codes are logical, could anyone tell me how to fix them?

Comment: I think you cannot directly use `beta`, `p1` etc. You first need to initialise them.

Comment: @RonakShah If I pre-set `beta, p1, p2 and x <- numeric()`, the warning message  `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` will occur and all variables are filled with `NAs`. I search this question online but still not know how to do.